# Calculation Problem C++

Tags: c++

I'm really new to C++, and this is homework. I don't understand what's going on. When I run this, everything works fine if I put in 60000 for current salary and .05 for pay increase, but if I put in something like 52000 for current salary and .23 for pay increase, then the retroactive pay comes out as 5982.00 instead of 5980.00. Is it something to do with the decimals or something? I don't really know. Thanks in advance.

```
// Variables
char fullName[30];  // The user's full name - INPUT
int currentAnnual;  // The users's current annual salary - INPUT
float percentIncrease; // The percent increase due on the
                       //   current annual salary - INPUT
// The retroactive pay
float retroactive;
// The new monthly salary based on the pay increase and the new salary
float monthlySalary;
// The new salary the user should receive based on their old salary
    //      and their pay increase
float newSalary;

for(int lcv = 1; lcv <= 3; lcv++)
{
    // INPUT
    cout << "What is your full name? ";
    cin.getline(fullName, 30);
    cout << "What is your current salary? ";
    cin >> currentAnnual;
    cout << "What is your pay increase (please input percentage in"
            "decimal format)? ";
    cin >> percentIncrease;

    // PROCESSING
    newSalary = (currentAnnual * percentIncrease) + currentAnnual;
    monthlySalary = newSalary / 12;
    retroactive = (monthlySalary - (currentAnnual / 12)) * 6;

    // OUTPUT
    cout << endl;
    cout << fullName << "'s Salary Information\n";
    cout << left << setw(15) << "New Salary" << setw(19) << "Monthly Salary"
            << "Retroactive Pay\n";
    cout << setprecision(2);
    cout << fixed;
    cout << right << setw(10) << newSalary << setw(19) << monthlySalary
                << setw(20) << retroactive << endl << endl;
    cout << "<Press enter to continue>";
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');
    cin.ignore(1000, '\n');
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: With all the warts and complexity C++ has, it's unfortunate that you have to learn it as a first language.

Comment: @Brennan: what an unhelpful and misguided comment... there's categories for closing questions that are as deliberately argumentative as that...

Comment: I took a year class that was in Java, but that was in highschool so it's been a few years, so it's technically not my first language. But to many others in my class it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
currentAnnual / 12
```

The division of two integers in C is an "integer division" (it gives an integer), and I think you dont want that. One solution is to change it to `currentAnnual / 12.0`. Anyway, it's important that you understand what is happening here.

Answer (score 2):

Change `currentAnnual / 12` to `currentAnnual / 12.0` to force a floating-point calculation to be done. Otherwise, that part of the computation will be rounded off to the nearest integer below.

Comment: Where did I talk about newSalary?

Comment: Oops -- That was meant to be added to Elafer's answer, not yours. I apologize.

Comment: Spot on... the currentAnnual of 52000 / 12 would be 4333.33333... mathematically, but because currentAnnual is also a float it's rounding off the fractional part.

Answer (score 0):

You should do `monthlySalary = newSalary / 12.0;` instead of `monthlySalary = newSalary / 12;`
 so you have to specify that you want to divide on float number. Otherwise result will be integer. For example `125./12 = 10` but `125./12. = 10.41(6)`. And of course you get wrong results.

Try to add `.0` or just `.` to all your constants.

Comment: `newSalary` is already a float.  `float / int` yields a float, not an int.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point calculations are not as accurate as you might expect.  Try replacing `float` with `double` in the above code (`double` is a "double-precision floating-point number"; it can store many more values than a `float`, and is much more accurate).

Also, order of operations is sometimes significant, so you may want to re-order the `retroactive` calculation to something like

```
6 * monthlySalery - currentAnnual / 0.5;
```

and try other combinations to see what works best.